# 404 error when I redeploy a war on Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, jakarta-ee

I tried to deploy a war file on *Wildfly* (commandline) by changing the name of the old file (say `app.war` to `appOld.war`) and copying a new file with the name `app.war` to the deployment folder. 
On my other terminal, I can see the auto deploy scanner running and deploying the new file but when I try to access the app via URL, I get a 404.
No error shows up in the logs so I don't realize what is happening or what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem with your context root.

Because if you don’t set context root wildfly takes filename as your context root.

When you deploy file you just renamed try access `<hostname>:<port>/appOld` instead of `<hostname>:<port>/app`

Context root can be manually set set in /WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

Here is the example of jboss-web.xml whit context root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/my-web-app</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

So when you set it you should be able to access yout app at: `<hostname>:<port>/my-web-app`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Kiki for your answer, the context root was the problem.